How to change a progress dialog to indicate dismiss instead of cancel?
I am currently writing a wxWidgets application as a tool to perform a task. This task is asynchronous and occurs in a different thread. I pop up a dialog box & disable the main window when the task starts with a description label and progress bar to indicate task progress. Below the progress bar is a "Abort" button that the user can press to stop the task. For some tasks, this progress box disappears automatically when the task is done.
My main concern is that certain tasks might require the user to be aware that the task has finished. In my mind, I would approach this by keeping the progress dialog box open when the task is complete with a completion description and a 100% progress bar. This would leave the "Abort" button in a useless spot, and no way for the user to close the progress dialog without hitting the title bar's close window button which is not accessible by keyboard. Would it make sense to change the label on the abort button to "Dismiss" once the task is completed, or would changing the button label confuse the user? Should I have two buttons?

The most common handling of a situation like this would be a separate screen on progress completion. That could be what you're proposing here indirectly.
If the progress bar disappears and "Abort" becomes "Dismiss", that's a new screen to your user. Doesn't really matter if it's the same screen technically, both button and copy switch so it's a new screen.
Can you add copy along the lines of "[task] has finishes successfully. Click Dismiss to exit task/process handler" into the screen once the progress bar completes?
Also, I would highly recommend "Cancel" and "Finish" over "Abort" and "Dismiss"

–The most common handling of a situation like this would be a separate dialogue/screen on progress completion.– Github and Netlify doesn't work like this, everything happens in the same window.

By separate screen I meant to reference new information in same window. Like an installer for instance, only 1 window but multiple screens. While the install is processing we have one screen with a progress bar and cancel button. When the install completes we see a completion message and Finish button, same window yes but a different user facing screen/dialogue. Edited answer to remove the word "dialogue"
